# FontAwesome Icon Picker Plugin For Bootstrap not showing

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

I want to use fontawesome picker on my website.
I followed this tutorial: 
https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-FontAwesome-Icon-Picker-Plugin-Bootstrap.html

I added the two files in my project fontawesome-iconpicker.js and fontawesome-iconpicker.css

My input:

```
<input class="icp demo" value="fa-anchor" type="text" name="iconTest">
```

My JS:

```
$('input[name="iconTest"]').iconpicker();
```

I see no javascript error and when I click on the input, nothing happens.
No Error, nothing.

I use Bootstrap and jquery in my application.

Update.
The div is created but not visible:

```
<div class="iconpicker-popover popover fade bottom in" style="display: block;top: 421px;left: 6.5px;max-width: 1819px;z-index: 99999999999;">
```

When I change display:block to display:contents it is shown.

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a repro via jsfiddle or using the snippet-feature of the site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used now the font icon editor in this way:

```
$('input[name=value]').iconpicker({placement: "inline"});
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, the i-class always needs to be `fa fa-arrow` instead of just `fa-arrow` or `fas fa-arrow`. Perhaps it is the same problem here but for the value?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
.fade.in {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some context as to how this solves the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Update this class in fontawesome-iconpicker.css (note the addition of opacity: 1):

```
.iconpicker-popover.popover.bottom,
.iconpicker-popover.popover.bottomRightCorner,
.iconpicker-popover.popover.bottomRight,
.iconpicker-popover.popover.bottomLeft,
.iconpicker-popover.popover.bottomLeftCorner {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```